# Profiling COM libraries used from a .NET Application

Tags: profiling

I am looking for a performance profiler that is able to profile a C++ library that is being called from a .NET Application.

I tried Purify+ without success (I don't get the calls the COM library) and a few others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AQTime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the IBM or AMD tools? They're really low level (being made from processor makers!) and so maybe they can profile your component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread that may be of use for you:
[Decent profiler for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170036/decent-profiler-for-windows)

xperf might be good.

I know that at a previous job my group used vtune successfully.